# Need to make few fields READ ONLY while exporting an SSRS report to excel(xls) IN VS2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement in an SSRS report to make few fields as READ ONLY after the report is exported to excel.

I need to do to export a report to excel, in this case, the user can not change the data in few fields in file.

How do we achieve this in SSRS? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to do this within SSRS. :(

If you wanted to waste a lot of time doing this, you could create an SSIS package to do it after the Excel report was create by SSRS.

Open the file, select you fields to make read only then set them to locked and **Protect** the sheet.

```
Range("K16").Select
Selection.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```